# How To Create Sub Query in NHibernate XML File

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I m Beginnner in NHibernate

I want To Have This Select In NHibernate XML File
i have google it but i could not implement it (implementing Sub Query is my problem )

```
select a.*,b.*,C.*
 From aa a Inner Join bb b  ON a.id = b.id  
 AND a.id IN (Select Max(id) From a Where a.id = b.id) 
 Inner Join cc c ON c.id = a.id
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I see many things wrong with the query.. first of all in the subquery there is no reference to `b` hence `b.id` is incorrect.

secondly two froms is incorrect you need to have just one  just do a select * if you want to select everything.

thus

```
Select * from aa a inner join bb b on a.id=b.id  inner join cc c on c.id=a.id 
WHERE a.id in
(Select Max(id) from aa A inner join bb B on A.id=B.id)
```

Comment: Dear @Baz1nga  That Part Of Code Was Converted By My Colleague. Sorry For Mistakes . How Would it be Be in Nhibernate XML Mapping File . you only fix that query mistakes !